# Image galley with Jquery (click on "next" button)

Tags: jquery

first of all sorry for my bad grammar as English is not my first language.

Anyway, I'm totally new to Jquery / Javascript.

I'm trying to create an image gallery with image swap effect using Jquery.

What I want to achieve is, when I click on a thumbnail (let's say No. 4), the main image would display image No. 4. Well, I've already successfully written a code for this matter.

Now, there's another thing I want to achieve:

I have a "next"-button. If the main image is displaying image No. 4, clicking on the "next"-button should result in the main image displaying image No. 5. Or, if the main image is displaying image No. 7, clicking on "next"-button would show image No. 8 and so on.

Using the code I've written, clicking on the "next"-button will cause the main image showing the 2nd image. Clicking it again then it shows the 3rd image, but not the next No. from where I clicked the thumbnail.

This is my Array:

```
var bilder = ["../../images/galerie/assassin_2_01.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_02.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_03.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_04.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_05.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_06.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_07.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_08.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_09.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_10.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_11.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_12.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_13.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_14.jpg",
              "../../images/galerie/assassin_2_15.jpg"];
```

This is my Jquery:

```
function mainimage(nr) {
    $("div.mainimg ul li:eq(0) div img").fadeOut({"duration":300, complete:function() {
        $(this).attr("src",bilder[nr]).fadeIn(500);
    }});
}
function next() {
    if (index < bilder.length) {
        index++;
        mainimage(index);
    }
}
```

And this is my HTML-structure:

```
<div class="mainimg">
    <ul>
        <li><div><img class="img1" src="../../images/galerie/assassin_2_01.jpg" /></div></li>
    </ul>
        <div class="caption">
            <div>Assassin's Creed 2</div>
            <div><a href="#">back/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="next();">next</a></div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbsrow">
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(0);" /></div>
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(1);" /></div>
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(2);" /></div>
</div>
<div class="thumbsrow">
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(3);" /></div>
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(4);" /></div>
    <div class="galeriethumbs"><img onclick="mainimage(5);" /></div>
</div>
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above you just need to set the index variable when on your mainimage function.

```
function mainimage(nr) {
        $("div.mainimg ul li:eq(0) div img").fadeOut({"duration":300, complete:function() {
            $(this).attr("src",bilder[nr]).fadeIn(500);
            index = nr; //this will set the index of the currently selected image.
        }});
    }
    function next() {
        if (index < bilder.length) {
            index++;
            mainimage(index);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you maintain the `index` variable? perhaps you need to set it when you call `mainimage function`

Comment: I've set "index" as a global variable. Setting it in "next()" function where I call "mainimage" function will cause the main image to swap the image only once. By the way index has a value of 0 (var index = 0;)